# numpy. Питон не изменяет элемент списка. (не модифицирует) Алгоритм Гаусса для СЛАУ

Tags: python, numpy

Моя программа должна решать СЛАУ c квадратными матрицами без ФСР алгоритмом Гаусса. СЛАУ представлено в виде Ax = f.

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
A = np.random.rand(n, n)
f = np.random.rand(n)
```

В программе я написал алгоритм Гаусса (без выбора главного элемента) для приведения к верхнему треугольному виду.

```
for k in range(n):
    A[k] = A[k] / A[k][k]
    f[k] = f[k] / A[k][k]#Элемент f[k] не меняется!
    for i in range(k + 1, n):
        A[i] = A[i] - A[k] * A[i][k]
        f[i] = f[i] - f[k] * A[i][k]#Аналогично! Тоже не меняется
        A[i][k] = 0
```

Так же присутствует код обратного хода для нахождения решения СЛАУ

```
for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    x[i] = f[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        x[i] = x[i] - A[i][j] * x[j]
```

Самое интересно, что алгоритм прямого и обратного хода (кроме изменения вектора f, разумеется) выполнено правильно, так как выполнение обратного хода дает точно такое же решение что и решение с помощью метода `numpy.linalg.solve(A,f)`

Основная проблема в том что когда я выполняю алгоритм Гаусса элементы вектора f не меняются, и не могу понять почему. Из-за этого я получаю совершенно другое решение СЛАУ. У меня даже нет предположений почему питон не хочет работать с элементами вектора f.

Для удобства ниже я приведу полный код своей программы:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
A = np.random.rand(n, n)
f = np.random.rand(n)
x = [0] * n

print('MATRIX A:\n',A)
print('VECTOR f:\n',f,'\n\n')


#ПРИВЕДЕНИЕ К ВЕРХНЕЙ ТРЕУГОЛЬНОЙ МАТРИЦЕ
for k in range(n):
    A[k] = A[k] / A[k][k]
    f[k] = f[k] / A[k][k]#Элемент f[k] не меняется!
    for i in range(k + 1, n):
        A[i] = A[i] - A[k] * A[i][k]
        f[i] = f[i] - f[k] * A[i][k]#Аналогично! Тоже не меняется
        A[i][k] = 0
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////#

#РЕШЕНИЕ СЛАУ
for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    x[i] = f[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        x[i] = x[i] - A[i][j] * x[j]

#///////////////////////////////////////////#

print('MATRIX A:\n',A)
print('VECTOR f:\n',f,'\n\n')


AA = A
ff = f
xx = np.linalg.solve(AA, ff)

print('My solution:\n',x)
print('Numpy solution\n',xx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При выполнении деления A[k] на A[k][k], в блоке приведения к верхней треугольной матрице, вы получаете по диагонале 1, т.е. A[k][k] == 1, потом вы делите на 1, что и приводит к тому, что матрица f не меняется при выполнении действия.

Просто добавьте print в функцию и вы сами увидите:

```py
#ПРИВЕДЕНИЕ К ВЕРХНЕЙ ТРЕУГОЛЬНОЙ МАТРИЦЕ
for k in range(n):
    print("A[k] = ", A[k], "A[k][k] = ", A[k][k])
    A[k] = A[k] / A[k][k]
    print("A[k] = ", A[k], "A[k][k] = ", A[k][k])
    print("f = ", f[k], "A[k][k] = ", A[k][k])
    f[k] = f[k] / A[k][k]#Элемент f[k] не меняется!
    print("f = ", f[k], "A[k][k] = ", A[k][k])
    for i in range(k + 1, n):
        A[i] = A[i] - A[k] * A[i][k]
        f[i] = f[i] - f[k] * A[i][k]#Аналогично! Тоже не меняется
        A[i][k] = 0
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////#
```

Как вариант решения, можете сделать так (выдает ответ как у numpy):

```py
#ПРИВЕДЕНИЕ К ВЕРХНЕЙ ТРЕУГОЛЬНОЙ МАТРИЦЕ
for k in range(n):
    f[k] = f[k] / A[k][k]  # Элемент f[k] не меняется!
    A[k] = A[k] / A[k][k]
    for i in range(k + 1, n):
        f[i] = f[i] - f[k] * A[i][k]  # Аналогично! Тоже не меняется
        A[i] = A[i] - A[k] * A[i][k]
        A[i][k] = 0
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////#
```